# TextBox Value Change = Other tool items disable

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb.net-2010

I need your assistance to do the changes in my project.

whenever text box value changes, i need to disable the radio buttons ,labels , text boxes and other tools ().

Actually i am moving the values from data grid to text box by using button click event. when i do that, text is moving but conditions aren't working

Already i tried this but it is not working. assist me.

```
  Private Sub txtIEG_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtIEG.TextChanged

    If txtIEG.Text = "RR1" AndAlso txtIEG.Text = "RR2" Then

        lblStatus.Visible = False
        cborderstatus.Visible = False
        lblticketno.Visible = False
        txtTicket.Visible = False
        lblPR.Visible = False
        txtPR.Visible = False
        lblPOno.Visible = False
        txtPOno.Visible = False
        rbneworder.Visible = False
        rbreprocessed.Visible = False

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can never be true:

```
If txtIEG.Text = "RR1" AndAlso txtIEG.Text = "RR2" Then
```

the TB might be "RR1" or it might be "RR2" but it can never be both at the same time.  Maybe you meant:

```
If txtIEG.Text = "RR1" OrElse txtIEG.Text = "RR2" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting their `Enabled` property instead of `Visible`

```
lblStatus.Enabled = False
cborderstatus.Enabled = False
```

etc.

**EDIT:**

Now I see, you are checking if your text is `RR1` AND `RR2` at the same time. It's kind of impossible, so the code in the if will never be executed. Change it to

```
If txtIEG.Text = "RR1" OrElse txtIEG.Text = "RR2" Then
```

Comment: Nope, it is not working :-(

Actually i am moving the values from data grid to text box by using button click event. when i do that, text is moving but conditions aren't working.